# Get sum over last entries per day per article

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

Let's say there is a table structured like this:

```
ID | article_id | article_count | created_at
---|------------------------------------------
1  |     1      |      10       | 2019-03-20T18:20:03.685059Z
2  |     1      |      22       | 2019-03-20T19:20:03.685059Z
3  |     2      |      32       | 2019-03-20T18:20:03.685059Z
4  |     2      |      20       | 2019-03-20T19:20:03.685059Z
5  |     1      |      3        | 2019-03-21T18:20:03.685059Z
6  |     1      |      15       | 2019-03-21T19:20:03.685059Z
7  |     2      |      3        | 2019-03-21T18:20:03.685059Z
8  |     2      |      30       | 2019-03-21T19:20:03.685059Z
```

The goal now is to sum over all `article_count` of all `article_ids` for the **last entries** per day and give back this total count per day. So in the case above I'd like to get a result showing:

```
total   | date
--------|------------
  42    | 2019-03-20
  45    | 2019-03-21
```

So far, I tried something like:

```
SELECT SUM(article_count), DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at)
FROM myTable
WHERE created_at IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.created_at::date, article_id::int) created_at
FROM myTable a 
ORDER BY created_at::date DESC, article_id, created_at DESC
)
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at)
```

In the distinct query I tried to pull only the latest entries per day per `article_id` and then match the `created_at` to sum up all the `article_count` values. 
This does not work - it still outputs the sum of the whole day instead of sum up over the last entries.

Besides that I am quite sure that there might be a more elegant way than the where condition.

Thanks in advance (as well for any explanation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to filter down to the last entry per day for each article:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at), SUM(article_count)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.created_at::date, article_id::int) a.*
      FROM myTable a 
      ORDER BY article_id, created_at::date DESC, created_at DESC
     ) a
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at);
```

Comment: This actually looks like what I want to achieve. Somehow, using this query, I get the error (pq: column "article_count" does not exist) ... what definitely cannot be the case since I am using article_count from that table in other cases already. Ok, I think there is just missing the article_count column in the distinct on query.

Comment: @grenzbotin . . . The subquery just needs to select all the columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this feature, is only for postgres?

Comment: @daniherrera . . . `distinct on` is a Postgres extension.  Many databases are also derived from the Postgres code base, so some of them also support it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for rank function:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT article_id, 
                article_count, 
                Date_trunc('day', created_at)  AS some_date, 
                Row_number () 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY article_id, Date_trunc( 'day', created_at) 
                    ORDER BY created_at DESC ) AS n 
         FROM   mytable) 
SELECT Sum(article_count) AS total, 
       some_date 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  n = 1 
GROUP  BY some_date
```

Just add the first of each day / article.

Check it at https://rextester.com/INODNS67085